# Search Big Array inside collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search

I have an array of probabilities created by a specific algorithm whose mission is
Create any name in Arabic as opposed to in English.

Some Arabic names have a potential of 92 million names in the English language
After creating this array, I am required to search for the corresponding name in the database in another English language.

In other words, the probabilities array that contains 92 million probabilities, I want to verify whether there is a name for them that matches in the database,
My primary problem is the slow handling in a for loop for all array and find its one by one, and took too much time?
Is there a way for me to divide this array into multiple arrays and at the same time search for the corresponding name in the database by using something like a parallel in Nodejs, or any Idea to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "fully exploit hardware", you can develop your own storage system and write your own search algorithm.

Otherwise your question needs more focus as to what it is you are asking.